# ERROR in The target entry-point "side-drawer-directives" has missing dependencies:

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

Having issues since upgrading to NS7. Have fixed most errors googling, but this one is striking me out - please any assistance would be appreciated. When I 'ns run ios' or 'ns run android', I receive the following error -
ERROR in The target entry-point "side-drawer-directives" has missing dependencies:

- ./..
- tns-core-modules/ui/page
- nativescript-angular/element-registry
  most stackoverflow suggests editing ngcc.config.ts, but after editing still getting same error.

My ngcc.config.ts currently looks like this (copied from other SO examples) -

> module.exports = {
> "packages": {
> "@nativescript/angular": {
> entryPoints: {
> ".": {
> override: {
> main: "./index.js",
> typings: "./index.d.ts",
> },
> ignoreMissingDependencies: true,
> }
> },
> ignorableDeepImportMatchers: [
> /zone.js//,
> /tns-core-modules//,
> /@nativescript/core//
> ]
> },
> "nativescript-localize": {
> entryPoints: {
> ".": {
> override: {
> main: "./angular.js",
> typings: "./angular.d.ts",
> },
> ignoreMissingDependencies: true,
> },
> },
> ignorableDeepImportMatchers: [
> /@nativescript/core//
> ]
> },
> "nativescript-datetimepicker": {
> entryPoints: {
> ".": {
> override: {
> main: "./index.js",
> typings: "./index.d.ts",
> },
> ignoreMissingDependencies: true,
> },
> "angular": {
> override: {
> main: "./index.js",
> typings: "./index.d.ts",
> },
> ignoreMissingDependencies: true,
> }
> },
> ignorableDeepImportMatchers: [
> /tns-core-modules//,
> /@nativescript/core//,
> /@nativescript/angular//
> ]
> },
> "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": {
> entryPoints: {
> "angular": {
> override: {
> main: "./side-drawer-directives.js",
> typings: "./side-drawer-directives.d.ts",
> },
> ignoreMissingDependencies: true,
> },
> "side-drawer-directives": {
> override: {
> main: "./side-drawer-directives.js",
> typings: "./side-drawer-directives.d.ts",
> },
> ignoreMissingDependencies: true,
> },
> },
> ignorableDeepImportMatchers: [
> /tns-core-modules//,
> /@nativescript/core//,
> /@nativescript/angular//
> ]
> },
> "nativescript-ui-listview": {
> entryPoints: {
> "angular": {
> override: {
> main: "./listview-directives.js",
> typings: "./listview-directives.d.ts",
> },
> ignoreMissingDependencies: true,
> }
> },
> ignorableDeepImportMatchers: [
> /tns-core-modules//,
> /@nativescript/core//,
> /@nativescript/angular//
> ]
> }
> }   }

This all started when I upgraded to NS7 with Angular10

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. I'm having trouble finding the right path.

Comment: You should upgrade nativescript-ui-sidedrawer to v9. Previous version has dependencies on the nativescript-angular/